# E-mail client with focus on managing multiple accounts

Tags: windows-7, email, email-client

I am seeking, for Windows 7, an e-mail client that allows the user to painlessly use many e-mail addresses (possibly from different domains).  I have seen a couple similar questions, but I have a few requirements:

- Free, and void of popups (might want to have it on while running full screen applications)
- Should be as easy as possible to toggle between addresses in the GUI, without logging out of one account to get into another
- No information from one e-mail account (name, e-mail address, etc.) should be visible to someone who interacts with another
- I should be able to easily select which e-mail address I am sending from, and any metadata sent with the e-mail should reflect only my selected address
- Should include the option to play a jingle when a new e-mail is received at a particular address(es)

Strongly desired bonuses:

- Option to start silently in the task bar tray on Windows start up
- Ability to send and/or receive text messages (from my own cell phone number if possible)

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer here, but my answer [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1010/94) applies to your question as well. Claws Mail can do what you need. It has its drawback (non-intutive UI) but besides that it can do what you desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can recommend [**Thunderbird**](https://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/).

It’s a

- cross-platform (GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows),
- Free/Libre Open Source,
- gratis available

email client from Mozilla.

#### Multiple accounts

Managing multiple accounts is easy and works great. Each account has its own settings, and each account can have several identities/aliases (each with its own email address, name, and signature), with one being the default/main address for this account.

All accounts are listed in a sidebar, in a folder tree (with all their email folders as children). You can switch to different views, e.g., showing only email folders with unread emails.

I’m using Thunderbird for many years with +/- 15 accounts and 40 email addresses. Works like a charm.

#### When composing an email

The `From` field becomes a select list, where you can choose which email address to use. It displays the chosen name and the email address for each entry. Aliases are grouped under their accounts.

If you compose a new email while being in a specific account (e.g., browsing its folders), the account’s default email address is automatically selected. The same is the case when answering an email (it selects the email address the original email was sent to).

#### When a new email arrives

You can [disable overlay notifications](https://superuser.com/q/87367/151741) under <kbd>Options</kbd> → <kbd>General</kbd>. After this, the only times you should see pop-ups are cases of warnings/errors, e.g., if it can’t connect to an account.

By default, you can enable [playing a sound](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/how-customize-new-mail-sound) only globally, i.e., for all accounts (there’s an old [feature request to change this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=311640)). There are some add-ons that allow to customize this:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/mailbox-alert/ (based on folders)
- https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/tonequilla/ (based on filters)
- https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/soundplus/ (based on contacts/threads)

I can’t recommend one, as I’ve never used audio notifications. Judging from their descriptions, [ToneQuilla](http://mesquilla.com/extensions/tonequilla/) seems to be suitable for your case: create a filter that fires when your selected email addresses are used in the `To` field.

#### Windows 7 integration: minimize to task bar

The add-on [Minimize On Start and Close](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/minimize-on-start-and-close/) (which I have never used) seems to make it possible for Windows 7 (emphasis mine):

> Instead of minimize the window to the tray it **minimize it to the taskbar**. It **can minimize on startup**, when the window is closed and/or when the esc key is pressed.

Related wiki entry, maybe of interest: [Minimize to system tray](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Minimize_to_system_tray_%28Thunderbird%29).

---

For questions about using/configuring it, Super User seems to be a good place, with [more than 1000 Thunderbird questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird).